# If $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences, then give a direct argument that $ (x_n + y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The caveat is that I cannot use the *Cauchy Criterion* in the proof, i.e. I cannot use the fact that *A sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence* in the proof.

So, what I can work with: A *Cauchy Sequence* is one such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ so that whenever $m,n \geq N$, it follows that $|a_n - a_m|< \epsilon$

This is where I'm at in the proof:
Given: $x_n$ is Cauchy, so there is an $m_1,n_1 \geq N_1$ such that $|x_n - x_m|< \dfrac{\epsilon} {2}$

and

$y_n$ is Cauchy, so there is an $m_2,n_2 \geq N_2$ such that $|y_n - y_m|< \dfrac{\epsilon} {2}$

Using the triangle inequality,

$|(x_n + y_n) - (x_m + y_m)|=$

$|x_n - x_m) + (y_n - y_m)| \leq$

$|x_n - x_m| + |y_n - y_m| < \dfrac {\epsilon} {2} + \dfrac {\epsilon} {2} = \epsilon$

For $\max[N_1, N_2]$

I think I have it, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it.
Thanks!

Comment: That **is** the way to do it.

Comment: That looks fine to me. What kind of improvement are you hoping for?

Comment: That's pretty much it: just chase definitions. $\qquad$

Comment: It seemed to be the only way @Thomas, since I couldn't use convergence to prove it. I was just making sure. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the Cauchy Criterion does not work under some circumstances, but this argument continues to hold.

Comment: When you are given very less, and asked to use even smaller results, you're better off working from definition. That's what you will learn, even in fairly advanced analysis courses - of course, you're correct, and you can't do better, can you?